# System.getProperty("user.home") on Tomcat returns "/usr/share/tomcat7/"

Tags: java, file, tomcat, getproperty

My Java Application runs on Tomcat and I want to create files under user home directory (such as `"/home/USERNAME/"`).

Method `System.getProperty("user.home")` works great on Windows, returning `"C:\users\USERNAME\"`. But on Linux it returns `"/usr/share/tomcat7/"`, on which my application haven't permission. I've tried `System.getProperty("user.name")` and it returns `"tomcat7"`. I've made a workaround but I'm not satisfied.

So, how do I get the user home directory, even when running on any OS and on Tomcat? Thanks.

Comment: What user or user.home do you expect on the linux system?

Comment: @soilworker, I wanted to create a file at `"/home/USERNAME/mydirectory/myfile"`, but as answered below, I shouldn't make it this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These properties i.e: user.* are relative to the user which is used to run tomcat. Normally on windows (local development workstations) we use the logged in user to run tomcat. So you are getting the correct values.(values which you think are correct). But on linux and specifically on productions environments, tomcats is always run using a restricted user account which normally is named as 'tomcat' itself. So there when u hit user.* properties you get the values specific to environment variables set for the user that tomcat is running as. Whats happening with you is the right way it should. You should not rely on these properties for your use.

Comment: Ok, I understand. However, I just need a directory to save files. Where should I create them?

Comment: most of the folks do it in temp env property. you can create your own property for such cases or create shared properties in catalina.properties file. Google a bit to find the approach which works best for you.

Comment: You probably want to use [Files.createTempDirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-).

Comment: Ok, thank you all. I'll study the ways to do it. I'll mark this answer as solution if there isn't any other. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Glad to see someone trying it out first and then asking queries. Many would help here for that.

Comment: Im also facing the same problem, how to go to "/home/varman/", please give me any idea.